# Printing dynamic DOM data in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery

My target is to fetch the data from all the textarea boxes (as added by user), to console.log. With my current code, it's only fetching from first box.

[image: Page Structure]

[image: Current Output]

HTML

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group" id="testID">
        <div id="afield">
          <textarea rows="2" cols="160" class="form-control nField" name="nameField" placeholder="Enter address here." required ></textarea>
          <br>
        </div>

          <div class="col-sm-11">
            <p class="help-block">Hit the + to add more fields.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addBtn" style="margin-top:5px!important;">
              <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addSubmit">
            Save
          </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
$('#addBtn').click(function(){
    var addField = $('<div id="afield"><textarea rows="2" cols="160" class="form-control nField" name="nameField" placeholder="Enter address here." required ></textarea></div><br>');
    $('#afield').append(addField);
  });
  $('.addSubmit').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#testID').map(function() {
        return {
            Address: $(this).closest('form').find('[name="nameField"]').val()
        };
    }).get();
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(jsonString);
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As mentioned by Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34581619/2422013),

```
$(this).closest('form').find('[name="nameField"]').val()
```

Can return only the first value.

You can use this instead:

```
var address = []
$(this).closest('form').find('[name="nameField"]').each(function(i,v){
    address.push($(v).val());
});
return {Address: address}
```

Comment: I tried doing console.log(address); after your code but it's not printing anything. I'm just a beginner so just learning.

Comment: this should work with code posted in question, not after any changes as per praveen's answer.
you need to replace: 
`return {
            Address: $(this).closest('form').find('[name="nameField"]').val()
        };`
from your code with the code given. you can use console.log before return statement.

Comment: You are the man! It worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot bro. Now I better go understand the logic behind it. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Sachin: It would be nice if you could edit clarifications directly into the answer and not in the comments. This would improve your answer, because it becomes easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe try this:

```
  $('.addSubmit').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
    var address = []
    $(this).closest('form').find('[name="nameField"]').each(function(i,v){
        address.push($(v).val());
    });
    var data = {Address: address}
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(jsonString);
  });
```

Comment: I got to this answer from your meta post. Now that the answer seems solving OP's problem, could you expand this answer by explaining the reason why OP's approach didn't work, and why your approach works? (e.g. try providing the official reference/documentation to help future readers). Thank you.

Comment: If you think about it, answers generally shouldn't start with the word "or".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett How about "I don't know"? People use that alot on their daily life. It's an answer.

Comment: @andrew-t, jean-françois-corbett: this wasn't the answer mentioned there. it was my other answer. I added this answer for further clarification, because the OP was not able to understand my previous question and code added in comment section will not be much understandable. I understand I should edit my answer for any clarifications, and will do that from next time. For now because the op has accepted it, I think I should not edit it anymore...

Answer (score 1):

If you are duplicating `id`, then it will not work.

```
var addField = $('<div id="afield"><textarea
//-------------------------^^^^^^
```

Also, `$(this).closest('form').find('[name="nameField"]').val()` could fetch the value of only one. You may need to change your structure to:

```
<textarea name="address[]"> <!-- note the [] -->
```

And get the output using `$("#formId").serialize()`. I can show you a simple example:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".add").click(function () {
    $(this).before('<textarea name="address[]"></textarea>');
    return false;
  });
  $(".show").click(function () {
    alert($("form").serialize());
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
textarea {display: block; resize: none; width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 0 0 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea name="address[]"></textarea>
  <button class="add">Add</button>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
</form>
```

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/xakibohina**

Comment: Thanks for the superfast reply Praveen.

I did all the changes you recommended. Changed `ID to Class`; used `[ ]`; used `serialize()`. Output is also being fetched, but two problems have arose.

1) When I click add button now, it doubles the no of textarea boxes. 1 > 2 >4 >8. It should add only 1.
2) serialize() also outputs "name". What if I want only value so that I can create a JSON out of it ? How to do that ?

PS: Also I didn't exactly understood the purpose of adding `[ ]`. If you can please explain or point towards some resource.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SujayKirti 1. Omg... Doubles? Are you cloning? That's not the right way. 2. `[]` creates an array of values.

Comment: Initially, it was not doubling but after I changed the IDs to classes you pointed out, it is acting like that. But I'm not using clone(). You can check out the code in the OP. Anyway, what's the best practice to do this ?

Comment: Done buddy. Now please help me getting the right output. Thanks

Comment: @SujayKirti yes.. What'd your expected output?

Comment: Just to fetch the values in console.log entered in those boxes, preferably in JSON, not mandatory though. Only Values, not with the name as it's coming with serialize().

Comment: Sorry bro, but the other answer worked out before you did. BTW the jsbin you posted works as well. I guess each() is something which was missing. PS: No hard feelings bro, your help is much appreciated. Thanks again. :)